# RowNumber function in page break expression returns invalid data type

Tags: ssrs-tablix

I am working on a SSRS report where I have to limit the rows in each page by 20.
So, in the tablix in my report which consists of many groups, I clicked on the parent group(the first most group) and got to the Properties window for the Tablix member. 
I updated the Page Break attribute the following way.

1. BreakLocation: End
2. Disabled: Floor((RowNumber(Nothing) - 1) / 20)

I don't get any error for the above expression but when I preview the report,
I get a warning : `Warning               1              [rsInvalidExpressionDataType] The Disabled expression used in grouping ‘Nameofthegroup’ returned a data type that is not valid.`

I tried various fixes like converting the result to Int or format it to Number, but nothing worked.

I still get the warning.

While debugging, I just tried out `RowNumber(Nothing`) as the Disabled expression and I still get the warning. So I concluded the issue is in `RowNumber(Nothing)` part itself and not because `Floor` function returns a `double` data type.

Can I get some help in getting rid of the warning.

Comment: I use the 2012 version of BIDS

Comment: And each time I try a different fix I made sure to delete the DATA file and close the solution and again open and put the fix so that the warning from the previous try dint show up.

Comment: Disabled property needs a true/false value, could you try to cast the result to bool? such as IIF(Floor((RowNumber(Nothing) - 1) / 20) > 0, false, true)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That fixed the issue.